# Why do we use the pronoun "that" in this situation, not "it"?

Tags: pronouns

1)The climate of Busan is milder than **that** of Seoul

2)The climate of Busan is milder than **it** of Seoul

---

I know that #1 is right. But I wonder why we don't use a demonstrative pronoun "it", a pronoun which usually refers to something already mentioned in a sentence or piece of text.

Comment: We do not use the pronoun "that" here. We use the determiner "that" here. And that's because we have to use a determiner there, not a pronoun. "It" is only a pronoun, and cannot be used as a determiner.

Comment: Maybe give [this page](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/determin/pronoun.htm) a read.

Comment: Aaargh. Sorry @CandiedOrange, I meant Reg!

Comment: @CandiedOrange Although I have some sympathy with RD's analysis, ICE doesn't agree with him - at all. They say, very clearly, "As this table shows, determiners always come before a noun, but pronouns are more independent than this. They function in much the same way as nouns, and they can be replaced by nouns in the sentences above"

Comment: @CandiedOrange I'm waiting on ternterhooks!

Comment: @Araucaria Hmm, you seem to be fixating on this rule, "determiners always come before a noun,"  I don't see the word "immediately" in there.  But you may be correct.  If "that" is meant as a determiner it should be making clear which Seoul is being referred to.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Actually, I haven't had my weatabix this morning! Following CGEL (Huddleston and Pullum, 2002) those would be classified as fused determiner-head constructions, which do indeed have determinatives (their word for determiners) as heads. But previous grammars such as Quirk et al (from which department IGE comes) had no such *fused* analyses open to them, and would regard *that* as a pronoun in the above. I've been teaching beginner English students  all morning!

Comment: @Araucaria I can accept that.  So how would you explain why "it" is an inappropriate pronoun here?

Comment: @CandiedOrange Well, I don't believe in determiners at all! So I'm a freak that you'd have to discount. But I reckon it'll be hard for Reg here, if pressed because examples abound of pronouns being used in similar constructions, such as "No one should be more aware of it than we of the Shoals Area!". Tonnes of examples from Shakespeare as well as lots of modern ones. Well know ones too, such as "You of little faith" and so on and so forth. He could of course say that *we* is a determiner here. But then that just begs the question ... :)

Comment: @CandiedOrange Which is my kind of saying that I can't ;)

Comment: *Thou shalt not covet it which belongs to thy neighbor.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the common belief, a pronoun can replace a whole noun phrase, instead of a noun.

And that is why the following phrase is incorrect -

> A new shirt (a noun phrase, with **shirt** it's head) -> A new **it** (Incorrect)

In your sentence we need something to replace the **climate** in **the climate of Seoul**. The noun phrase is **the climate of Seoul**. We can use a pronoun to replace the total noun phrase, but not a noun inside a noun phrase. So to solve this problem we need to use another class of words. We call them **Pro-form**.

The word **that** can be used as a **Pro-form** here, but the word **it** can't. That's why it's incorrect to say - **it of Seoul**.

The only correct version is **that of Seoul**.

> The climate of Busan is milder than **that** of Seoul

Comment: Just a note that some people classify the normal pronouns as a subtype of pro-forms (e.g. the Wikipedia entry on pro-forms). By doing this, though, they lose out on the distinction made by @Man_From_India between those (like 'that') that can be used sub-phrasally and those which cannot (like the normal pronoun 'it').

Comment: @Silenus There is no doubt that they do. A noun phrase can have more than one word, or just a single word. If they are the single word, it's none other than the head noun. In these cases both **Pro-form** and **pronoun** are the same. **Pro-form** is not restricted to **nouns** only, they can replace other class of words too.

Comment: Hi @Man_From_India, I wasn't disagreeing with anything you said in your post. Only pointing out that you seem to suggest that pronouns are not pro-forms (which runs against some syntactic classifications, like the one on Wikipedia). I guess the problem is with your sentence: "The word 'that' can be used as a Pro-form, but the word 'it' can't." If I understand how you're using "pro-form", you might consider changing it to "The word 'that' can be used as a pro-form HERE, but the word 'it' can't."

Comment: @Silenus Oh thanks :-) I will edit my answer for more clarity. I didn't mean to say that pronouns are not pro-forms. I will edit it.

Comment: @Man_From_India But how about "We of the National Union of Teachers do not believe that ...", for example?

Comment: @Araucaria I have been thinking about it and found hardly anything regarding this problem. But then again I think not all words can act like a "pro-form". For example - "He decided to play football, so did Adam". In this sentence **did** is the pro-form of the verb, and **so** replaces the rest. *Adam did so* = *Adam decided to play football*. Similarly in OP's particular problem *that* can act like the way it did in his quoted sentence, but *it* can't.